# Nesting class structures gives compiler errors

Tags: typescript

I have a class hierarchy like this:

User:

- roles: Role[]

Role:

- permissions: Permission

Each class has a constructor that converts the args into its designated class, for instance User converts roles into Role instances. Role converts permission into Permission instance.

Sample code:

```
const user = new User({
        roles: [
            {role_name: 'admin', permissions: {'*': '*'}} 
        ]
    })
```

When I pass JSON for user, with the nested permission object, I get compiler errors, because Permission has methods on it. `Property 'has' is missing in type '{ '*': string; }' but required in type 'Permission'.`

How can I avoid these issues?

Edit:

How can I enable the Roles class to accept the permissions as an object so that it can correctly coerce the JSON to the Permission type?

```
// users.ts
export interface User extends BaseModel {
    createdAt?: string;
    updatedAt?: string;
    email?: string;
    username?: string;
    fullname?: string;
    microsoftId?: string;
    roles?: UserRole[];
}

export class User {
    constructor(props?: Partial<User>) {
        if(!props){
            props = {};
        }

        props.roles = props.roles?.map(role => new Role(role)) || [];
        
        Object.assign(this, props);
    }

    hasPermission(service: string, perm: PermissionType){
        for(let role of this.roles || []){
            const has = (role.permissions as Permission).has(service, perm);
            if(has){
                return has;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

// roles.ts


export interface Permission {
    [key: string]: PermissionType[]|any;
}

export class Permission {
    constructor(props: Partial<Permission>){
        Object.assign(this, props);
    }

    has(service: keyof Permission, permName: PermissionType|undefined): boolean {
        //.....
    }
}
export interface Role extends BaseModel {
    createdAt?: string;
    updatedAt?: string;
    role_name?: string;
    description?: string;
    scopes?: string[];
    permissions: Permission;
}
export class Role {
    constructor(props?: Partial<Role>) {
        if(!props){
            props = {};
        }

        props.permissions = new Permission(props.permissions || {});
        
        if (!Array.isArray(props.scopes)) {
            props.scopes = [];
        }

        Object.assign(this, props);
    }
}
```

Comment: You defined a class `Permission` which has a `has` method. Your `{ "*": "*" }` doesn't have that method and therefore is not a `Permission`.

Comment: Hi @SilvioMayolo - I clarified my question a bit. I want to allow plain objects in the constructor - but have them correctly coerced to the correct Permission type. This data is originating from a server REST response (as JSON) so I need to coerce them to get the methods added/etc.

Comment: Then when you receive the JSON data, convert it to Permission objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't name the interface the same as the class. You're merging the names and creating a frankly rather awkward setup. Have a separate interface for constructor arguments.

```
export interface PlainPermission {
    [key: string]: PermissionType[]|any;
}

export class Permission implements PlainPermission {
    [key: string]: PermissionType[]|any;

    constructor(props: Partial<PlainPermission>){
        Object.assign(this, props);
    }

    has(service: keyof Permission, permName: PermissionType|undefined): boolean {
        //.....
    }
}
```

and the same for `Role` and `User`. Then you have a clear distinction: `PlainPermission` is the "plain" Javascript object you pass to constructors and `Permission` is the thing with all the nice, convenient methods attached to it.

When you define an interface and a class with the same name, they get merged to create one larger class, and `Permission` is defined to be "anything that has the stuff from the interface *and* a `has` method", which is not what you want.

You're going to have to duplicate the field names from the interface in the class, but that makes sense: an interface is a promise to implement something, whereas a class is the actual implementation. One is a contract, the other does the work stated in the contract. You can use `implements PlainPermission` as an extra check to make sure you implemented the interface correctly.

Comment: That makes sense - the reason I had them named the same though is so that Permission class gets all the properties automatically from the interface. I don't think that carries through in your example.

Comment: See my edit. You won't be able to get the names automatically, but you can verify that they're correct using `implements`.

Comment: Okay - that's good to know. As an alternative, would it be a bad idea to have a `PlainPermission` class (named the same as the interface) with no methods - and then have the `Permission` class extend this `PlainPermission` class?

Comment: That would probably work. To be honest, I'd look at it funny, because `PlainPermission` (the way you're using it) is intended to be used as an interface, so having it declared as a class is a bit awkward from a readability standpoint. But functionally, it does what you want.

Comment: Yeah I've struggled with this aspect of typescript for some time. My goal is to be able to pass plain object data into a class and get the properties assigned without having to duplicate much code. Maintaining those props in 2 different places adds some overhead. So using the interface eliminates that because the class constructor can accept the plain object.

Comment: I would challenge the frame of your question in that case. Why do you have all these classes that are identical to ordinary Javascript objects and only have public, writable fields? That's contrary to the point of classes. I would argue that, if you intend all the fields be public, you should be using ordinary `{ ... }` objects for everything and letting methods like `hasPermission` be top-level functions. Leave the classes for things that are encapsulating behavior you want to hide.

Comment: Alternatively, if you like being able to do `.hasPermission`, consider having `Permission` *contain* a `PlainPermission`, rather than trying to make it share all the properties. Just store a single JS-style object inside your class and reference it. See [Composition over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: Those are valid points and good suggestions. I think I can move forward on this. Thanks!